# HTML li class=youarehere not working

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

am doing a HTML website, and I have a main menu - *Home, About etc*.
I have several html pages and for each page I want the menu li to change color to **#E38400**.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="youarehere"><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my style.css code:

```
.header #nav ul li .youarehere {
    background:#E38400; border-radius:5px; color:#FFF;
    }
```

but the first list item still shows the same color etc. I want to use neither jQuery nor any other script, but why is this not working?

Comment: .header #nav ul li.youarehere a? http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ecfgsv13/

Comment: No, I don't want to change the a color. Never mind, someone already answered it for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to remove li or place .youarehere just with li without space :

```
.header #nav ul li.youarehere {
  background:#E38400; 
  border-radius:5px; 
  color:#FFF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now your **define** in your **css** this `.header #nav ul li .youarehere` but **actually** you define this `.header #nav ul li.youarehere`  because your apply to this class in `li` .

**as like this**

```
.header #nav ul li.youarehere {
    background:#E38400; border-radius:5px; color:#FFF;
    }
```

=================================

**Demo**

```css
#nav ul li.youarehere {
        background:#E38400; border-radius:5px; color:#FFF;
        }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="youarehere"><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><h3>menuITEM</h3></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between `li` and `.youarehere`

like this -

```
.header #nav ul li.youarehere {
background:#E38400; border-radius:5px; color:#FFF;
}
```